# How can I upload file and send checkbox using java servlet?

Tags: java, html, forms, servlets

How can I upload multi file and send checkbox using java servlet?

What method is best way to use?

Post?

What about `enctype` in html form?

What will be the code in java servlet ?

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="checkbox"  name="notifi-user-via-email" id="notifi-user-via-email" value="notifi-user-via-email">
<input type="file" name="fileUpload" id="files" size="50" multiple/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Thank you for your explain!

Comment: Why did you create a new account and ask the exact same question you posted 4 hours ago?

Answer (score 0):

`enctype` should be set to `"multipart/form-data"` as you have done. POST or GET doesn't matter. You should have a `@Multipart` annotation in your Servlet where you receive the HTTP Request. Refer this: [JavaEE Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html)